# With Drupal Commerce, how to configure product for "on request"?

Tags: commerce

I'm sure this is detailed somewhere, but I haven't had an luck in finding an explanation/description...

I have a website based on Drupal Commerce (new version to be released is based on Kickstart 2). I would like to have a product which is available "on request". This differs from my current products, which are either available or not; managed via the Stock module.

Is there some way to set up suitable rules, or even a module, to manage such a situation? Ideally I would like to have a separate button - "on request", for the product display (as can be set-up through the normal configuration for any of the displays) - for such products, assuming it's possible. A customer could order the product, I (or the team) would receive the request, we'd review the order, and have a discussion with the customer about lead time, etc., etc.

Anyone is free to point me in the direction of where this type of functionality is already described! My thanks (and apologies) if this case.

Thanks!